# Ubuntu 18.04 is not able to shut down properly

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, shutdown, windows-10

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 on a dual boot mode on my PC alongside Windows 10. Initially, there was no glitch with the system, however after a while Ubuntu is not able to shut down properly. It is showing the below APCI error. If I have to properly shutdown, I restart and go to boot Windows 10 and shut down. Can someone throw some light on it?

[image]

Comment: Does this computer have discrete graphics GPU or does it have integrated graphics with the CPU?

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem that occurs when your PC vendor advertises it supports an ACPI function but doesn't actually implement it. Effectively, it's telling Linux that it *can* handle some function, like shutdown, but when Linux tries to use it, no such function exists.

See this [Debian mailing list thread](https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2017/04/msg00698.html)

The main cause of this is that likely the vendor decided not to implement something as a hardware feature and instead coded it into a driver they load in Windows. You can check if the vendor has provided a newer version of the BIOS or if any options exist in the BIOS to enable functionality for other OS's.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As I recall, I am getting this error after I updated the BIOS update from OEM. However, the link for understanding what is happening is clear.